# Can not render data from mongo db in react js front end

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose, axios

I have written a backend code in nodejs using expressjs and I have a list of doctors stored in mongodb database and I am using mongoose. I have tested the api end point in postman and I am getting correct output there but when I try to render the same data in my reactjs app then I get empty table.
Can anyone help me with this?

Following is my code.

Following is the backend code

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
mongoose
  .connect("mongodb://localhost/mongo-exercises")
  .then(() => console.log("Connected to Mongo DB"))
  .catch((err) => console.error("Could not connect to mongo db", err));

const doctorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  serialNumber: Number,
  yearOfRegistration: Number,
  registrationNumber: String,
  medicalCouncil: String,
  name: String,
  fathersName: String,
});

const Doctor = mongoose.model("Doctor", doctorSchema);

app.get("/api/doctors", async (req, res) => {
  const doctors = await Doctor.find();
  res.send(doctors);
});

app.listen(6000, () => console.log("listening on port 6000"));
```

and this is the react front end code

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Doctors extends Component {
  state = {
    posts: [],
  };
  async componentDidMount() {
    const { data: posts } = await axios.get(
      "http://localhost:6000/api/doctors"
    );
    this.setState({ posts });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="m-2">
        <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Serial Number</th>
              <th>Year of Registration</th>
              <th>Registration Number</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Medical Council</th>
              <th>Father's Name</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.state.posts.map((post) => (
              <tr key={post._id}>
                <td>{post.serialNumber}</td>
                <td>{post.yearOfRegistration}</td>
                <td>{post.registrationNumber}</td>
                <td>{post.medicalCouncil}</td>
                <td>{post.name}</td>
                <td>{post.fathersName}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Doctors;
```

Comment: You are expecting `posts` in the server response, but you are just sending an array of doctors on the server. You should `console.log` the response from axios (don't destructure it) and find out the format of what you sent down. You will probably have to change the server to send down a JSON containing the doctors array.

Answer (score 0):

you can use fetch method in react to get all data

```js
const [data, setData] = useState([])
await fetch('url')
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((result) => useData(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use relative paths like `/api/doctors`

If your server is running on a different port than your react app, try setting up a proxy - https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

I would recommend reading the whole page, but the important part is to put this in the package.json that is managing your react app.

From the docs:

"To tell the development server to proxy any unknown requests to your API server in development, add a proxy field to your package.json, for example:

`"proxy": "http://localhost:4000",`"